# New item in the list disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click the submit button to add a new item react renders it for one second then it disappears.
When I check the array the item isn't added, no idea why :(

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/etasbasi/pen/RjoMMm?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<div id='root'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: ["basketball", "tv", "monopoly"],
      current: ''
    };

    this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add() {
    let arrayvar = this.state.items.slice();
    arrayvar.push(this.state.current);
    this.setState({ items: arrayvar });


    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.items[i]);
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ current: event.target.value });
  }

  getItems() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.items[i]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.add}>
          <span>New item: </span>
          <input id='input' type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div>{this.state.items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li>)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was happening was that on form submit an `action` is triggered which by default points to the containing pages url if none is provided. On submit, a request is sent based on the action (`get`/`post`) provided and then the page reloads.

You have to prevent the default behaviour of the form on submit. [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
  add(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ...
  }
```